# System of differential equations using Laplace transformations.

Tags: laplace-transform, transformation, differential

I need to solve the following using Laplace transformations (and inverses):

$x' + 3x + y' = 1$

$x' - x + y' - y = e^t$

where:

$x(0)=y(0)=0$

Using Laplace transformation I got following equations:

$sX + 3X + sY = 1$

$sX - X + sY - Y = \frac{1}{(s-1)}$

where:

$X = L(x(t))(s)$

and:

$Y = L(y(t))(s)$

$\rightarrow (s+3)X + sY = 1$

$(s-1)X + (s-1)Y = \frac{1}{(s-1)}$

By subtracting I now have:

$(s+3)X + sY = 1$

$4X + Y = \frac{(s-2)}{(s-1)}$

Multiplying first equation by $(\frac{-1}{s})$ and adding it to second one I ended up with:

$((\frac{-s-3)}{s})+4)X = \frac{(s-2)}{(s-1)} - \frac{1}{s}$

Finally I have:

$X = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3(s-1)^2} - \frac{1}{3(s-1)}$

I now want to use inverse Laplace to $x(t)$ but we didn't define what is Laplace inverse of a constant (for $1/3$ in this case).

Once I have $x(t)$ I know how to finish a task, so my question is did I do something wrong so far in this task and if not what is Laplace inverse of $1/3$?

Comment: $L(1) = \frac 1s$

Comment: I need inverse Laplace of 1

Comment: Your transformation for the first line should be $sX(s)+3X(s)+sY(s) = \frac 1s$

Comment: Oh, didn't see that mistake, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

$$x' + 3x + y' = 1$$
Taking Laplace transform gives:
$$sX(s)-x(0)+3X(s)+sY(s)-y(0)=\frac 1 s$$
$$sX(s)+3X(s)+sY(s)=\frac 1 s$$
$$x' - x + y' - y = e^t$$
Taking Laplace transform again gives:
$$sX(s)-x(0)-X(s)+sY(s)-y(0)-Y(s)=\frac 1 {s-1}$$
$$sX(s)-X(s)+sY(s)-Y(s)=\frac 1 {s-1}$$
So we have the following system:
$$
\begin{cases}
(s+3)X(s)+sY(s)=\dfrac 1 s \\
X(s)+Y(s)=\dfrac 1 {(s-1)^2} \\
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
X(s)=\frac 1 3 \left (\dfrac 1 s -\dfrac s {(s-1)^2} \right )  \\
Y(s)=\dfrac 1 {(s-1)^2} -X(s)\\
\end{cases}
$$
Taking inverse Laplace Transform we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
x(t)=\dfrac 1 3 \left (1-e^t-te^t \right )  \\
y(t)=\dfrac 1 3(4te^t-1+e^t) \\
\end{cases}
$$